# xCode build failed: Module 'connectivity_plus' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, build

I am developing a flutter app and running on iOS Simulator works fine in Android Studio, and it works well when building from terminal `flutter build ios`. But when I try to build from xCode (so I can create an archive and release the app), I get this error:

Module 'connectivity_plus' not found

I used to use connectivity, and then the error was Module 'connectivity' not found.

I have found some similar questions, but none of the suggested answers worked for me. I have tried:

```
flutter clean
rm -rf /ios/Pods
rm -rf /ios/Podfile
rm -rf /ios/Podfile.lock
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
```

I uncomment this line in Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

That is the iOS Deployment Target as well, so they match.

```
flutter build ios
```

That works ok, but when I open Runner.xcworkspace in xCode and build, I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`. not `apt get`

Comment: @MendelG That's what I was doing, I wrote it down wrong. Editing the question.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the files on Xcode DerivedData folder and doing the steps above?

Answer (score 0):

You have been opening xcode project from ios/Runner.xcodeproj,

> Try to open xcode from ios/Runner.xcworkspace and clean build and
> rebuild the porject, after that you wont be having this error.

Hope this will help you resolve your error.

Happy Coding..